# Why is the iPad display 9.7 inches rather than a rounded value such as 10 inches?

Tags: ipad, display

The iPad display is 9.7″ diagonally. Why is it not a rounded value such as 10″? Are these display sizes magically invented?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because questions asking why Apple did X are not welcome. Please edit this so there is a practical question to be solved. The [help guide](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) explains how to be specific and show how your research didn't help you solve this dilemma.

Comment: Please do. I already got my answer from a user below, explained scientifically. Plus, I read through the Asking section in the Help Center you provided and found my question fail no requirement, and how this is a dilemma while it only has one explanation.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A screen is manufactured at x pixels * y pixels, probably measured in microns or nanometres, which will give a final measurement for x * pixels and y * pixels in millimetres.

Pythagoras figured out that the diagonal measurement of a right-angled triangle [the hypotenuse] is the square root of the sum of the squares of the other two sides…. again this would nominally be in millimetres.

Then someone has to figure out what that is when converted back to the creakily aging Imperial measurement system still used in the USA & others [UK too]

The end result is very unlikely to come out to a round number of inches.

Comment: According to Wikipedia article "Pixel" http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pixel, a pixel does not need to be a square. means that the height and width are not in identical measurement, so basically Pythagorean theorem cannot be applied here, and they can freely scale the pixel to fit the pre-designed diagonal length, the diagonal length doesn't have to follow the pixel?
And please provide citations instead of "probably" information.

Comment: I think you're missing the point of my reply.

Comment: I really do. Please enlighten me.

Comment: Making the screen, corner to corner, an exact number of inches [a measurement system used by very few countries in the world] is simply not a prime concern. Even if they did that, what about the people who wanted an exact number of inches for the height & width? Would they just be forgotten about, ignored in favour of the corner to corner lobby?

Comment: So if you are saying that the diagonal length is not a rounded value because the width and the height are already standard values. Then I think I got the idea. Thank you.

Comment: >.< I'm happy you're happy. Please feel free to mark my answer as the correct one ;)